# How do I install Apache with PHP support and the MySQL server on centos without using any ready-to-use packages like WAMPServer or XAMPP?

Tags: centos

How do I install Apache with PHP support and the MySQL server on centos 6.4 desktop environment without using any ready-to-use packages like WAMPServer or XAMPP ?

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? What were the results? Where, exactly, are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 2):

### Installing Apache with PHP support:

Apache comes with centos default packages. So you can install through yum package manager along with that install httpd, mod_ssl also.

Configure the httpd.conf and adjust firewall setting for your system.

For php support install packages required using the following command:

> yum install php-mysql php-devel php-gd php-pecl-memcache php-pspell php-snmp php-xmlrpc php-xml

Restart the apache.

### Installing MySQL:

MySQL is also in centos default packages so install using yum. If not installing through yum , then download the following package and install using yum or package manager GUI.
[MySQL for Red Hat Enterprise linux.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=459921).

I hope it helps.